# IPhone NSURLConnection Delegates

Tags: iphone

In my application i am checking username and password using  webservice .i used NSURLConnection class but before the execution of NSURLConnection delegates my authentication metod works.how to contorl after the response come it continous the normal execution

Comment: What you mean by normal execution ? What you getting now ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do something after the end of web services..
there are couple of methods..
like .. - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

check NSURLConnection documentation..